# Using JNA to pass a struct containing an array of doubles from Java to C

Tags: arrays, struct, jna, primitive

I have a C function that expects a struct which contains an array of doubles:

```
typedef struct ArrayHolder {
    int numVals;
    double* vals;
} ArrayHolder;

void putArrayHolder(ArrayHolder* holder);
```

I tried to handle this in Java as

```
public interface CLibrary extends Library {
    public static class ArrayHolder extends Structure {
        public static class ByValue extends ArrayHolder implements Structure.ByValue {}
        public static class ByReference extends ArrayHolder implements Structure.ByReference {}

        public int numVals;
        public double[] vals;
    }

    void putArrayHolder(ArrayHolder.ByReference holder);
}

...

CLibrary.ArrayHolder.ByReference holderRef = new CLibrary.ArrayHolder.ByReference();
holderRef.numVals = 3;
holderRef.vals = new double[3];
holderRef[0] = 1;
holderRef[1] = 2;
holderRef[2] = 3;
clib.putArrayHolder(holderRef);
```

Unfortunately, the above Java code led to the C function receiving corrupted data - the "numVals" value seemed to come through ok, but the "vals" array was corrupted.

What am I missing here? What is the correct way to set up this sort of structure - containing a primitive array - in Java in order to pass it to a C function via JNA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your structure does not contain a primitive array.  It contains a pointer to double, which is assigned the address of an array of doubles.

Your `vals` field must be of pointer type (nominally `Pointer`).  You can then use your choice of an NIO buffer or `com.sun.jna.Memory` to allocate the space for the array of doubles.